# Filestream in Sql Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream

i tried to get it to work but i never seem to have to luck, i go a code snippet for a blog and still no dice. This is the code.

```
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

CREATE DATABASE NorthPole
ON
PRIMARY (
  NAME = NorthPoleDB,
  FILENAME = 'C:\Temp\NP\NorthPoleDB.mdf'
), FILEGROUP NorthPoleFS CONTAINS FILESTREAM(
    NAME = NorthPoleFS,
FILENAME = 'C:\Temp\NP\NorthPoleFS')
LOG ON (                        
    NAME = NorthPoleLOG,
FILENAME = 'C:\Temp\NP\NorthPoleLOG.ldf')
GO
```

Comment: We'll need a lot more than that to go on. What, exactly, isn't working?  What error message are you getting, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable filestream on the server, on the database you're going to use it and after all this, create a table with filestream type.

Try the steps described in the linked below:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1838

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1850

or read here:

1)**How to: Enable FILESTREAM**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx

2) **How to: Create a FILESTREAM-Enabled Database**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645585.aspx

3) **How to: Create a Table for Storing FILESTREAM Data**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645583.aspx

Please, provide more information on what kind of issues you've faced, if this steps won't help.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I agree we need more info however here are a few points that you might have missed.

You need to make sure the filestream is enabled, to do this you can use the SQL Server configuration manager. Right click on the SQL Server and select properties. Go to the filesteam tab and make sure all the options are ticked.

After you then setup the filestream filegroup you will then be free to add filestream columns to a table