# Is there an alternative of using a VBScript for enabling FileStream after SQL Server installation?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, filestream

To use Filestream on a DB 3 steps must be done:

1) enable it a server/instance level

2) enable it (`sp_configure`) at DB level

3) create a `varbinary(max)` field that supports filestream

(2) and (3) are done easily with T-SQL

(1) is doable manually from SQL Server Configuration Manager, basically what I need is to check all the 3 checkboxes:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sql-server-performance.com](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/admin/article_images_new/2008_images/Configure_Filestream_in_SQL_Server_2008/Image2.jpg))</sub>

but how is it possible to automize it?

I found this artcile ["Enabling filestream usin a VBScript"](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sqlsrvengine), is there another way to do it than using VBScripts? May be something that is possible to do only with 2008R2?

In case it VBScript is the only solution, which are the possible downsides?

Comment: You seem to have found a script that does what you want to do. Why isn't it suitable?

Comment: Yes I found the script, but I'd like to search for an alternative if possible, since I implemented all my system without using VBScripts, so if I could achieve the same effect without using a VBScript I would be happier.

Comment: Setting filestream access level to 2, you'll set filestream enable for transact_sql and i/o streaming access, as I wrote in my answer. What else do you need?

Comment: @hgulyan The VBScript sets the Window Share Name as well and maybe other stuff (I'm not sure exactly how it overlaps with what you posted)

Comment: @user193655 I think you could rewrite the VBS in a.NET solution using stuff in the  System.Management namespace but I'm not sure that is any closer to what you need?

Comment: I've edited my answer with share name setting

Comment: @Martin Smith Yes probably the solution is to rewrite the VBS in some other language. This is what I mean: scritp it self on my machine (Vista) dates back to 2001, so it is prone to deprecation in my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way other than clicking in the Configuration Manager is via WMI (which is what the VBScript does). If you don't like VB, here's how I've been configuring it from C# (note that the code needs to run with admin privileges (elevated)):

```
private ManagementObject GetFilestreamManagementObject(string machineName, string instanceName)
{
    string managementPath = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10", machineName);
    ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope(managementPath);
    managementScope.Connect();

    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("FilestreamSettings", string.Format("InstanceName='{0}'", instanceName));
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, query))
    {
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
        if (1 != moc.Count)
        {
            string exceptionText = String.Format("Expected single instance of FilestreamSettings WMI object, found {0}.", moc.Count);
            throw new FilestreamConfigurationException(exceptionText);
        }
        ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator enumerator = moc.GetEnumerator();
        if (false == enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new FilestreamConfigurationException("Couldn't move ManagementObjectEnumerator to the first entry.");
        }
        return (ManagementObject)enumerator.Current;
    }
}

private void EnableFilestream(int accessLevel)
{
    ManagementObject filestreamSettingsObject = GetFilestreamManagementObject("myMachine", "MSSQLSERVER");
    ManagementBaseObject methodArgs = filestreamSettingsObject.GetMethodParameters("EnableFilestream");
    methodArgs["AccessLevel"] = accessLevel;
    methodArgs["ShareName"] = ""; //default

    ManagementBaseObject returnObject = filestreamSettingsObject.InvokeMethod("EnableFilestream", methodArgs, null);
    if (returnObject == null)
    {
        throw new FilestreamConfigurationException("Result of calling filestreamSettingsObject.InvokeMethod(\"EnableFilestream\", methodArgs, null)" is null);
    }
    uint returnValue = (uint)returnObject.GetPropertyValue("ReturnValue");

    const uint errorSuccessRestartRequired = 0x80070BC3;
    if (returnValue != 0 && returnValue != errorSuccessRestartRequired)
    {
        Win32Exception win32Exception = new Win32Exception((int)returnValue);
        string exceptionText =
                string.Format("'EnableFilestream' method returned {0}: {1}", returnValue, win32Exception.Message);
        throw new FilestreamConfigurationException(exceptionText);
    }
}
```

Comment: In Addition: add using System.Management; and right click on references and add System.Management

Answer (score 3):

Just run this.

```
USE master
Go
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options'
GO
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 3
GO
EXEC sp_filestream_configure 
  @enable_level = 3
, @share_name = N'FS';
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

More on this

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1489

> 0 = disabled (this is the default)
>
> 1 = enabled only for T-SQL access
>
> 2 = enabled for T-SQL access and local
> file system access
>
> 3 = enabled for T-SQL access, local
> file system access, and remote file
> system access

You can store the script in a **stored procedure** and call it from your application or anywhere you want.

Here're links on this topic

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1838

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/filestream-configuration-and-setup-changes-in-sql-server-2008-february-ctp)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/Configure_Filestream_in_SQL_Server_2008_p1.aspx

**EDIT**

Answer to your comment.

Here's what I call step 2

```
CREATE DATABASE Archive 
ON
PRIMARY ( NAME = Arch1,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\archdat1.mdf'),
FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup1 CONTAINS FILESTREAM( NAME = Arch3,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\filestream1')
LOG ON  ( NAME = Archlog1,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\archlog1.ldf')
GO
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645585.aspx

Check link for all steps

[Filestream in Sql Server 2008 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795911/filestream-in-sql-server-2008-express/2801080#2801080)

Good Luck!

Comment: What you suggest is what I called step (2), I need step (1). I also added an image on my question to make it more esplicit what I want to automize.

Comment: Yes, but before this step it is mandatory to enable filestream in the configuration manager. That is the part I want to automize.

Comment: I think, you do something wrong. To enable filestream, changing access level is enough. I've edited the query. Try again.

Comment: i tried as you suggest, but if I run configuration manager and try top access to fielstream tab (as in the image in my question) I don't see the changes. While I see those changes if I try to use the VBScript I mention above. Moreover in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx they say in step 1-9 to do what I need and in steps 10-11 to do what you suggest.

Comment: moerover I even don't have sp_filestream_configure, it has been probably removed in 2008R2

Comment: sp_filestream_configure was only available in a CTP version of Sql Server and has been removed in the official release. Therefore I believe this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Pawel's solution worked great for us. We were seeing about a 50% failure rate using the VBS -- haven't seen a failure yet with Pawel's approach. Unlike Greg's results, it has worked great for us against a local system. Actually, that's all we have tried it with.

We did have to make a couple of adjustments to Pawel's code. The line

```
throw new FilestreamConfigurationException("Result of calling filestreamSettingsObject.InvokeMethod(\"EnableFilestream\", methodArgs, null)" is null);
```

has the final quote character out of place. It should be after the "is null", right before the ");".

We also had to make sure we got the instanceName built correctly. For example, if we had "mymachine\myinstance", we had to make sure that "instanceName=myinstance" and not the full name. Further, if we had "mymachine" (the default instance), we had to have "instanceName=MSSQLSERVER". Maybe that is Greg's problem -- when we had the instanceName set to the wrong thing, we got the same results Greg reports.